# Formatting \pagemark with LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

I am customizing my headers and footers with the document class `scrbook`. Now everything works fine **except that the `\pagemark` doesn't get formatted as intended (i.e., gray color, letter-spaced, etc.)**. I would like to format the `\pagemark` as it is with the headers. Also, all `\pagemark`s should appear on ALL pages (including the first pages of each chapter, as it has already been)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\lehead{\color{gray} \sffamily \textls{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}}
\rohead{\color{gray} \sffamily \textls{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}}
\lefoot[\pagemark]{\color{gray} \sffamily \textls{\pagemark}} % <--- The formatting doesn't take effects.....
\rofoot[\pagemark]{\color{gray} \sffamily \textls{\pagemark}} % <--- The formatting doesn't take effects.....


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Methodology}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: it is a lot easier to notice if you use `\textls{pagemark: \pagemark}` in the foot definitions.

Comment: And if you use `\typeout{\meaning\pagemark}` you get an idea as to what `\pagemark` contains and probably why your formatting does not apply (hint: `{\usekomafont {pagenumber}{\thepage }}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `\addtokomafont` and `\setkomafont` for the font settings in page header and footer.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}

\usepackage[markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}% 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}% or maybe \ofoot*{\pagemark} for page numbers on chapter pages

\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}% no chapter number in page header
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{gray}\sffamily\textls}% font settings for page header and footer
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}% no special font for page numbers

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Methodology}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```